# document.getElementById on another window

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to get the id of the previous parent window if you launched the child window with `document.location.href="diffPage.htm?name="+string;` where string would change each time?

Basically I have the main window with an `id=favouritesTab`, called main.html that goes to diffPage.htm when a function is invoked.

I have tried `window.parent.document.getelementById()` such as

```
var favouritesScreen = window.parent.document.getElementById('favouritesTab');
if(favouritesScreen.style.display == 'inherit')
{
    ..so on
```

But it doesn't seem to work at all. Does anyone know if there is a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that your page is hosted at the same domain, accessing a document in the original window is **possible** via the `window.opener` property.

A full demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/eAjqX/1/show/

1. Click on the button to open a new window.
2. Upon click in the new window, you will see that the body's content changes to the value of the input field.
3. Navigate away using the provided link, in the original page.
4. Repeat step 2. You will see that `window.opener.document.getElementById` still works.

The code for this demo (jQuery is not necessary):

```
// New window page:
var i = 0;
document.onclick = function (){
    try {
        alert(window.opener.document.getElementById('test').value);
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
};
// Launcher
window.open("http://jsfiddle.net/eAjqX/show");
```